# How do I reset password on salesforce.com

Tags: reset-password

Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce administrator.

I am assuming my password is locked for salesforce.com, how do I unlock this please

Answer (score 2):

Resetting Passwords
Available in: Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com Editions

User Permissions Needed
To reset passwords: “Reset Passwords and Unlock Users”
To reset a user’s password:

Click Your Name | Setup | Manage Users | Users.
Select the checkbox next to the user’s name. Optionally, to change the passwords for all currently displayed users, check the box in the column header to select all rows.
Click Reset Password to have a new password emailed to the user

Comment: Thank you Sahil, much appreciated

Comment: @RememberHasan If it helps you please do upvote . :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also reset password directly from the Workbench if you have Admin access[image]